# iOS Size Classes - What is the iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, size-classes

I'm trying to figure out which size class in Xcode is equivalent to the iPhone 6. Most websites say that it is the Compact Width | Any Height Choice. However, I've noticed that the width is 400 points for that choice while the iPhone 6 is 375 points across.

Is there no 1:1 relationship with an of the size classes? If not, why?

Comment: Compact Width | Regular Height is the same for iPhone 4, 5, 5S and 6. There cannot be a 1:1 size in InterfaceBuilder. Build with constraints so that it matches any screen with that Size Class and you'll be fine for all of them.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. It's actually a very clever strategy on Apple's part. The old way you used to be able to build apps without constraints if you did not want to use them and they'd look fine, now that is not possible.

Comment: You can if you want. It's a lot more work though and you have to disable size classes. It also means you'd have to create several nibs for each screen size etc...